# Сформировать коллекцию на основе "не равно"

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Есть две модели данных:

```
public class EquipmentProduktModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual EquipmentModel EquipmentModels { get; set; }
    public int ProduktId { get; set; }
    public virtual Produkt Produkt { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Produkt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите названия продукта")]
    [StringLength(450, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Название должно быть от 1 до 450 символов")]
    [Display(Name = "Название")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Примечание")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Артикул")]
    public string Articul { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Штрих код")]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Единицы измерения")]
    public virtual Unit Units { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Минимальное количество")]
    public decimal MinQuantity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Минимальный заказ")]
    public decimal MinZakaz { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EquipmentProduktModel> EquipmentProduktModels { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Учитовать в браке")]
    public bool BrakOn { get; set; }     

}
```

Как правильно создать коллекцию Produkts в которой исключены записи уже добавленные  EquipmentProduktModel.

Когда мы формируем запрос:

```
var List = from p in _context.Produkt
                       from s in _context.EquipmentProduktModel.Where(c=>c.EquipmentModelId == 1012)
                       where p.Id == s.ProduktId
                       select p;
```

То запрос создаст коллекцию из тех записей которые уже есть в EquipmentProduktModel.

Но если мы меняем

```
                        where p.Id != s.ProduktId
```

То из списка исключается только первая позиция из коллекции EquipmentProduktModel.

Как правильно сформировать коллекцию Produkts исключив те позиции которые уже внесены в EquipmentProduktModel.

Comment: Используйте `.Distinct()`.

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне негде проверить, но возможно так

```
var List = from p in _context.Produkt              
           where !_context.EquipmentProduktModel
                    .Where(c=>c.EquipmentModelId == 1012)
                    .Any(m=>m.ProduktId == p.Id)
           select p;
```

или так

```
var ids = _context.EquipmentProduktModel
                    .Where(c => c.EquipmentModelId == 1012)
                    .Select(c=>c.Id);

var List = from p in _context.Produkt              
           where !ids.Contains(p.Id)
           select p;
```

или так

```
var List = from p in _context.Produkt
           where !_context.EquipmentProduktModel
                    .Where(c => c.EquipmentModelId == 1012)
                    .Select(c => c.Id).Contains(p.Id)
           select p;
```

не уверен в эффективности запросов, но вроде корректные. Если есть ошибки, сорри, не работал с БД давно.